# Is there a way to catch multiple events of the same type at once?

Tags: javascript, events

I am developing a plugin for this big (and not very well documented) framework. I need to bind a Javascript function to an event. The problem is, this event is fired multiple times at nearly the same time (I have no control over that) and I need the function to be run only once, especially since there are some Ajax calls included in it.

I am not extremely familiar with Javascript, so this question might come as pretty stupid, but is there a way to somehow "buffer" the events for a short amount of time and when there are no more incoming, run the function?

Comment: What you might be looking for is something called `debounce` or `throttle`,  there are plenty of these implementation on npm, or if your say using something like lodash this comes with one too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually called `debouncing`. Here is a [good article](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/) regarding throttling and debouncing.

> The Debounce technique allow us to "group" multiple sequential calls in a single one.

There are multiple implementations listed in the article, but an example implementation could be (this version will call the event *at the end* of your multiple calls, once they have stopped firing for the specified amount of time):

```
function debounce(callback, duration) {
    let timer = null;
    let args = [];
    let thisVal = null;
    function trigger() { callback.apply(thisVal, args); }
    function onEvent() {
        thisVal = this;
        args = [].slice.call(arguments);
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(trigger, duration);
    }
    return onEvent;
}
```

Then you could call it using the following code for example:

```
function myEventListener(data) {
    // do your thing
}
window.addEventListener('my-event', debounce(myEventListener, 100));
```

which would prevent to call your event listener again until it stops being triggered for at least 100ms.